# Make the built in function len() in python

Tags: python, built-in, try-except

I'm trying to make a function to return the length of a list in python.

#### Code

```py
def get_len(arr):
    ind = 0
    try:
        x = arr[ind]
        while x is not IndexError():
            ind += 1
            x = arr[ind]
    except IndexError:
        return ind

print(get_len([1, 2, 3, "one", "two"]))
```

#### Questions

1. Is it wrong to use `try` / `except` to get the length ?
2. Are there other ways to do it ?
3. Which resources to see the implementation of built-in function `len` ?

Comment: `while x is not IndexError()` is not how you test for an error.

Comment: If what you have here is working, it would fit better on the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: @ScottHunter Of course he does, he mentions it in the question title.

Comment: The current source code for len() is here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bbcf42449e13c0b62f145cd49d12674ef3d5bf64/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1683 . Lists were built so they know their own length, they keep track of changes and don't need to count it out each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while x is not IndexError()` part is unnecessary (`x` will never equal an `IndexError()`).  Here's a simpler version:

```
def get_len(arr):
    ind = 0
    while True:
        try:
            arr[ind]
        except IndexError:
            return ind
        ind += 1


print(get_len([1, 2, 3, "one", "two"]))
```

The statement `arr[ind]` is sufficient to check for an error; if `ind` is equal to or greater than `len(arr)`, the subscript operator will raise (*not* return) an `IndexError`.

The actual built-in function is typically not going to be one that's defined in Python itself.  See for example the CPython implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L429

Note that the real `len()` function is much faster than a reimplemented version can be because the list already "knows" its length and can return it instantly without having to count up the items one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but it's just by accident. The `while` condition will always be true, because every call to `IndexError()` returns a new object, which is not the same object as any value in the list. You can replace that with just `while True:`.

The `try/except` is what detects the index error when you reach the end of the list.

There's no need to execute `x = arr[ind]` multiple times. Just put that inside the loop before incrementing `ind`.

```
def get_len(arr):
    ind = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = arr[ind]
        except IndexError:
            return ind
        ind += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative way of getting the length of a list or even arbitrarily long iterables, I've seen some library that had something like this to achieve that:

```py
from collections import deque

def get_len(it):
    try:
        res, _ = deque(enumerate(it, 1), 1).pop()
    except IndexError:
        return 0
    return res
```